# SQL showing the duplicate values issues

Tags: php, sql

I am using the following query in my project but the issues duplicate value is repeating. I have used the DISTINCT and GROUP BY also. Please help me.

Query :

```
SELECT
    dob.user_info.users_id AS user_id,
    CONVERT(
        nvarchar(50),
        dbo.chat_message.time
    ) AS chat_time,
    dbo.user_info.users_name AS user_name
FROM
    dbo.user_info
INNER JOIN
    dbo.chat_message ON dbo.user_info.eve_id = 19
AND dbo.user_info.user_id = dbo.chat_message.user_id
AND dbo.user_info.user_id <> 478 
AND dbo.user_info.user_type <> 'admin' 
AND dbo.chat_message.delete_status = 1 
GROUP BY 
  dbo.user_info.user_id, 
  dbo.user_info.user_name, 
  time
```

[image]

[image]

OUTPUT should be like

```
|505, mothan, Chk, 2015-03-23 10:24:15.000| 
|551,yasar, hi yasar how are you ?, 2015-03-16 16:41:49.000| 
|566, Jegan , hi jegan, 2015-03-16 16:41:07.000| 
|567 , Prabu, hi prabu, 2015-03-16 16:41:07.000|
```

if server date is equal to chat date then it should display only chat time. if server date is greater than the chat date then it should display the date like 24feb.

Comment: `distinct`  and `group by ` will work effectivly when there is aggregated data.

Comment: If you want to return only one row per user_id you have to specify which chat_time values etc you want in case of several rows for a user_id!

Comment: BTW, which dbms? (Convert is a product specific function.)

Comment: Sir, i cant get you. can u explain?

Answer (score 1):

Updated version:

```
with cte as 
(
SELECT dob.user_info.users_id AS user_id,
       CONVERT(nvarchar(50), dbo.chat_message.time) AS chat_time,
       dbo.user_info.users_name AS user_name,
       dbo.chat_message.message
FROM
    dbo.user_info
INNER JOIN
    dbo.chat_message ON dbo.user_info.eve_id = 19
AND dbo.user_info.user_id = dbo.chat_message.user_id
AND dbo.user_info.user_id <> 478 
AND dbo.user_info.user_type <> 'admin' 
AND dbo.chat_message.delete_status = 1
)
select * from cte t1
where not exists (select 1 from cte t2
                  where t2.chat_time > t1.chat_time
                    and t2.user_id = t1.user_id)
```

Comment: "Accept" revoked after 9 days?!? That's a bit odd. How come?

Comment: yes sir my result should be like max time for each user_id but this result shows only one user_id so that why sir.

Comment: Sir, i am searching for this solution but i am not getting the correct query sir. please help me sir

Comment: using this following query i can solve but the error is showing

Comment: SELECT ai.user_id,cm.friend_id, MAX(cm.time) AS time,(SELECT ai.user_name FROM dbo.user_info ai, dbo.chat_message cm WHERE ai.user_id = cm.friend_id GROUP BY user_name) AS user_name 
FROM dbo.chat_message cm INNER JOIN dbo.user_info ai ON ai.user_id = cm.user_id
GROUP BY ai.user_id,ai.user_name, friend_id

Comment: ERROR : Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: from stackoverflow i got the solution like (SELECT TOP 1 ai.user_name FROM dbo.user_info ai, dbo.chat_message cm WHERE ai.user_id = cm.friend_id GROUP BY user_name) AS user_name . if i use TOP 1 it is displaying the same name. But the name should be unique.

Comment: Actually, I can't see that my query gives you wrong result - it returns the rows where time = max time for that user_id. Can you please explain what's wrong with it's result?

Comment: Sir, i am doing the chatting application using php. I want to display the latest message for each user_id. But sir your query display only for max time for particular use id who has max time. I want max time for particular particular user id

Comment: @user3750938, now updated. Test and tell me how it goes!

Comment: Thank you sir, i worked out your query. if i give query like AND dbo.user_info.user_id = 478 then it is displaying the message id 6th record only . If i give query like AND dbo.user_info.user_id <> 478 then the table record is empty only.I have updated the table. I want the record of latest max time for each user id. For example the output should be like | 505, mothan, Chk, 2015-03-23 10:24:15.000 | 551,yasar, hi yasar how are you ?, 2015-03-16 16:41:49.000 | 566, Jegan , hi jegan, 2015-03-16 16:41:07.000 | 567 , Prabu, hi prabu, 2015-03-16 16:41:07.000 .

Comment: Another one sir. if server date is equal to chat date then it should display only chat time. if server date is greater than the chat date then it should display the date like 24feb.

Answer (score 0):

You have distinct time fields and so get multiple results.
If you take the time field out of the group by and use max(time) you will get the most recent time in your result.

```
SELECT dob.user_info.users_id AS user_id,
CONVERT(nvarchar(50), MAX(dbo.chat_message.time)) AS chat_time,
dbo.user_info.users_name AS user_name, dbo.chat_message.message FROM dbo.user_info INNER JOIN dbo.chat_message ON dbo.user_info.eve_id = 19 AND dbo.user_info.user_id = dbo.chat_message.user_id AND dbo.user_info.user_id <> 478 AND dbo.user_info.user_type <> 'admin' AND dbo.chat_message.delete_status = 1
GROUP BY dbo.user_info.user_id, dbo.user_info.user_name, dbo.chat_message.message
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But it is showing the same result only

Answer (score 0):

Very Good Question, Can you please try below one, if it works

```
SELECT
    Distinct dob.user_info.users_id AS user_id,
    CONVERT(
        nvarchar(50),
        dbo.chat_message.time
    ) AS chat_time,
    dbo.user_info.users_name AS user_name
FROM
    dbo.user_info
INNER JOIN
    dbo.chat_message ON dbo.user_info.eve_id = 19
AND dbo.user_info.user_id = dbo.chat_message.user_id
AND dbo.user_info.user_id <> 478 
AND dbo.user_info.user_type <> 'admin' 
AND dbo.chat_message.delete_status = 1 
GROUP BY 
  dbo.user_info.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply sir. The SQL server showing the following error below

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'ems.chat_message.time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.